# How can I improve my Turkish Small Capitals (lualatex)

Tags: accents

I am frustrated trying to obtain a proper looking Turkish "İ" letter in small caps using lualatex. Previous answers on this particular subject either do not work or are too complicated for me.

As of today, is there a relatively simple solution so that I can get the dot over i properly aligned?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont[Script=Latin,Language=Turkish]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\begin{document}
\textsc{\.{i} \.ı \.\i}
\end{document}
```

I can use a hacky solution since I need the letter in just a few (noticeable) places.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a collective failure to support Turkish really I think, we should do better, however since you say hacks are acceptable:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont[Script=Latin,Language=Turkish]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\begin{document}
\textsc{\.{i} \.ı \.\i (i) [ı] [ı̇] }

\textsc{\.{}\kern-.3emi}
\end{document}
```

To get `\i` to work you might also want to add the following to your preamble.

```
\let\oldtextsc\textsc
\def\textsc#1{\oldtextsc{\def\i{i}#1}}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I have now defined
    \newcommand{\Ii}{\.{}\kern-.3emi}
so that I can easily use your solution in the handful of places when I need.

On the other hand, I see that this has been going on for a long time. Is this something with Turkish only? When can we expect to see that this is not a problem anymore?

Comment: ...wait. I just noticed that, this time the dotless ı letter does not look right. I looks like l. (If I use i instead of ı, the look is OK in small caps but, of course, now the plain text has the wrong character.) How do I fix this?

Comment: @laissezfaire yes I noticed that (hence the various trials on the first line)  I suppose you want the version in round brackets made with `i` I think that `\i` and `ı` ought to give that but I'm not sure where the fault is. The duplicate question that is linked indicates that there are some errors in the font so it might be best to check the `\textsc` macro first with a different font and then if that works look to see if there is a font update. If it helps I could supply another hack so that locally within `\textsc` `\i` was defined to be `i` so that you get the correct small caps form.

Comment: This being due to a bug presents hacking as a valid approach, I think. I would appreciate a second hack so that I can get this nasty issue out of my mind, if for the present.

Comment: @laissezfaire code added

Comment: This does the job :-) Thanks very much. There is just one final thing though. See I have just migrated to lualatex just to have a fully searchable pdf. Now I am OK with some of the large title texts not showing up in searches but, of course, these titles are also not found in the toc, which becomes a valid source of concern. Is there a way to fix this by maybe adding these entries manually after first erasing the hacky ones?

Comment: Never mind. I should have remembered that I can use the optional [] argument of the \chapter, \section... commands. Thanks again for your help. I think this turned out to be a useful post offering a simple and practical way to overcome an annoying issue. (One thing to bear in mind is that the hack works with the \textsc command but not the \scshape command.)

Comment: @laissezfaire oh I made \textsc fragile, use `\protected\def\textsc#1{... ` then it will be robust again